# Как вернуть фокус на первое окно?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день! Сайт подбора отелей, помимо результатов нашего внутреннего поиска хочу показать результаты по тем же запросам на других системах поиска отелей. Для этого со своей формы собираю запрос в формате другой системы подбора и по клику на кнопку найти выполняю скрипт:

```
var myWindow = $(window); 
    myWindow.open(url,'_blank');
    myWindow.focus();
```

Проблема в том что фокус не возвращается на первое окно (вкладку точнее), т.е. я собственноручно увожу клиента на другой сервис. Мне нужно чтобы и окно "конкурента/партнёра" открылось и фокус на моём сайте остался. Чтобы пользователь если захотел мог сам перейти к партнёру и сравнить цены.

Как сохранить фокус а первой вкладке с моим сайтом?

Comment: со стороны конкурента window.opener.focus? см. http://javascript.ru/window.opener

Comment: @SanSYS почему то мне кажется что к стороне конкурента доступа нет.

Answer (score 1):

var popup = window.open(...); // открыть окно

popup.blur(); // открытое окно теряет фокус

window.focus(); // фокусируется на текущем окне

См.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181464/i-need-to-to-open-a-new-window-in-the-background-with-javascript-and-make-sure

Сорри, что без форматирования, пишет что мой браузер его не поддерживает

Comment: Или вот еще: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261784/making-a-window-pop-under-in-chrome

Comment: Вот не работает никак блиин =( вот репозиторий с тестовым примером где я пытаюсь то же самое сделать https://github.com/maler1988/js_window